# Bus error on neon implementation of summary SAD (Sum of Absolute Difference)

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I'm trying to code a neon version of Sum of Absolute Difference of a 16 uint8_t sized inputs:

```
inline static int f_sad_16(const uint8_t* a, const uint8_t* b)
{
  int sad = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    sad += abs(static_cast<int>(a[i]) - static_cast<int>(b[i]));
  }
  return sad;
}
```

The neon code I wrote:

```
inline static int f_sad_16_neon(const uint8_t* a, const uint8_t* b)
{
  int32_t r[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  uint8x16_t va, vb, vr;

  va = vld1q_u8(a);
  vb = vld1q_u8(b);

  vr = vabdq_u8(va, vb);

  uint16x8_t vr1 = vpaddlq_u8 (vr );
  uint32x4_t vr2 = vpaddlq_u16(vr1);
  uint64x2_t vr3 = vpaddlq_u32(vr2);

  vst1q_u64 (reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(r), vr3);

  return r[0] + r[2];
}
```

For some reason I get a bus error. My test program uses the `__attribute__ ((aligned (16)))` gcc directive for the two inputs, and I can see by the memory addresses assigned to them that the inputs are 16-byte aligned.

What can be the source of the problem?

Comment: On which source line do you get the bus error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `r` is properly aligned - change:

```
int32_t r[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

to:

```
int32_t r[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 } __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

Note however that it's unlikely that this routine will be beneficial, as it uses a significant number of both scalar and NEON instructions, which means it will most likely have performance similar to that of your original scalar implementation.

Comment: You're right, aligning r[4] eliminated the bus error. I'm still looking for the bugs you mentioned, my test program shows the expected results. If you have a test case where the bug would show itself I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: Sorry - I take it back about the bug(s) - I read the code too quickly. My comment about performance still stands though - it's unlikely that your NEON code will be significantly faster than a decent scalar implementation.

Comment: True. On a small skeleton test I saw a ~x1.7 speedup vs gcc (4.6.3) with -O3 enabled on regular C code. After some rethinking I got a solution which suites the need for SAD on 128 uint8's, which is the SAD value the algorithm I'm coding needs. Using vpadalq_u8 the 16 uint8's are sum reduced to 8 uint16's and accumulated. After the 8th iterations the partial sum gets reduced to 1 SAD value using vpaddlq. This gives a ~x7.5 speedup on my test program. All test runs were made on Cortex-A9.